# python mp3 meta-tag

Tags: python, meta-tags

I try to write a script than scan recursive a given directory and if found mp3 get and just print meta tag for it. What ever I passed to getEyeD3Tag I got an exception. Here is my code that i have written so far

```
  def getEyeD3Tags(path):
    try:
        trackInfo = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(path)
        tag = trackInfo.getTag()
        tag.link(path)
        print tag.getArtist()
        print tag.getAlbum()
        print tag.getTitle()

        #return (tag.getArtist(),tag.getTitle(),tag.getAlbum())
    except eyeD3.InvalidAudioFormatException:
        print "File %s is not a mp3 file " % path
mp3Num=0
temp=os.walk(valid-folder-name)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in files:
        if os.path.join(root,i):
            temp=os.path.splitext(i)
            temp[1].lower()
            if temp[1]=='.mp3':
                mp3Path=os.path.join(root,i)
                print mp3Path
                getEyeD3Tags(mp3Path)
                mp3Num+=1
                raw_input()
            #print "**"
        else:
            print "Error invalid path"
    print "\n\n"
    #raw_input()
print mp3Num
raw_input()
```

And BTW is it a way to get genre of mp3 file using eyeD3?
Thx in advance

Comment: What exception do you get?  The one you catch saying that it isn't a valid MP3 file or some other one?  I'd guess the latter as you have explained away the `InvalidAudioFormatException`; please post your actual error (as you should ***always*** do with all "I get an error/exception" questions).

Comment: Sorry my fault get always eyeD3.InvalidAudioFormatException the only one that I catch

Comment: Try adding `except eyeD3.InvalidAudioFormatException as e: print "Invalid file! " + str(e)` to see what the exception actually says

Comment: I get Invalid file!. File is not mp3

Comment: Is it actually an mp3? What does `file mp3file` say when you run it from a shell?

Comment: Could You please explain what are You have on Your mind because I don't really get it? I checked type of file in windows using property tab and it shows that is mp3 audio type

Comment: The problem is using eyeD3 under windows I guess. I run script in linux and works just great. I probably don't install the extension correctly

Answer (score 2):

To check if the file being parsed is a valid mp3, call the eyeD3.isMp3File(*filename*) method.

The following is from a short script I made to auto-sort my music folder.

```
def parseIDETag(self, path):
        if eyeD3.isMp3File(path):
```

That way, if the file isn't an mp3, it'll just skip over it.

Also, `str(tag.getGenre())` returns the genre as a string using eyeD3.